# Android: Orientation Issue

Tags: android, orientation

I have an activity that shows a video. I want this view to show only on landscape, so I have my AndroidManifest.xml as follow:

```
<activity
        android:name="uk.co.tangent90.ciscoDelegateBag.android.activities.ViewVideoActivity"
        android:label="@string/registerViewTitle"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" >
    </activity>
```

It is working almost fine:

- If I am in portrait, the view rotates as expected.
- If I am already in landscape, can happen 2 things:

  1. The view remain as it is. OK.
  2. The view rotate 180 degrees. NOT OK

It is depending on if I have the front camera in the right or in the left. So it is like android only recognizes ONE landscape orientation.

Has anybody have this problem before? Any easy way to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the minimum SDK level?

Comment: Api level 14 is the minimum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
```

Refer [`<activity>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen) documentation for values `screenOrientation` can take.

Comment: Yes, this did the trick. Thanks for the quick answer! (I will accept this answer in 3 min)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following?

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: Maybe you set the orientation in ViewVideoActivity. Can you post its code?

Answer (score 1):

Android recognizes only one rotation as landscape, the other, 180° degrees rotated "landscape" orientation is called "reverseLandscape", you can only use one of them, in fact, most of the apps that show videos only work in one orientation.

EDIT: try as Rajesh said "sensorLandscape"

Comment: Could you give me an example of an application that shows videos only in one orientation?

Answer (score 1):

Use [screenSize](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) if you are using minimum sdk version above 13.

> If your application targets API level 13 or higher (as declared by the
>   minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), then you should also
>   declare the "screenSize" configuration, because it also changes when a
>   device switches between portrait and landscape orientations.